# KNN classifier taking too much time even on gpu

Tags: machine-learning, knn

I am classifying the MNSIT digit using KNN on kaggle but at last step it is taking to much time to execute and mnsit data is juts 15 mb like i am still waiting can you point any problem that is in my code thanks.

```
import numpy as np # linear algebra
import pandas as pd # data processing, CSV file I/O (e.g. pd.read_csv)

import os
print(os.listdir("../input"))
#Loading datset

train=pd.read_csv('../input/mnist_test.csv')

test=pd.read_csv('../input/mnist_train.csv')

X_train=train.drop('label',axis=1)

y_train=train['label']

X_test=test.drop('label',axis=1)

y_test=test['label']

from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

clf=KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3)

clf.fit(X_train,y_train)

accuracy=clf.score(X_test,y_test)

accuracy
```

Comment: sklearn doesn't use the GPU, its normal that this method is super slow

Comment: From tensorflow you can import knn. And tensorflow use gpu, that might solve your problem

Answer (score 7):

There isn't anything wrong with your code per se. KNN is just a slow algorithm, it's slower for you because computing distances between images is hard at scale, and it's slower for you because the problem is large enough that your cache can't really be used effectively.

Without using a different library or coding your own GPU kernel, you can probably get a speed boost by replacing

```
clf=KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3)
```

with

```
clf=KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3, n_jobs=-1)
```

to at least use all of your cores.

Answer (score 0):

because you are not using gpu on kaggle actually. KNeighborsClassifier do not support gpu

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the GPU for KNN, you need to specify it otherwise it defaults to CPU the documentation is here: https://simbsig.readthedocs.io/en/latest/KNeighborsClassifier.html

knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3, device = 'gpu')